# calculating average over many files

Tags: python, perl, bash

I would like to calculate average value for data in multiple files: (about 10 files). Lets say I have file1.dat, file2.dat, file3.dat and ... file10.dat. 
Each file contains two columns. The "first column is line number" and the "**second column is the data**". In total I have 1800 lines in a file. The pattern of the data is shown below:

```
    1.00   0.659
    2.00   0.608
    3.00   0.578
    4.00   0.557
    5.00   0.543
    6.00   0.527
    7.00   0.514
    8.00   0.502
    9.00   0.489
    . 
    .
    .
 1800.00   0.480
```

I want to calculate average for **data** according to line numbers from each file. That means, I want to find average for the all first line data from file1, file2... and file10 and write in *new file*. Then average for the all second line data from file1, file2... and file10 and write in the same *new file*.

That *new file* supposed to have the format as below. For example;

```
    1.00   0.112
    2.00   0.324
    3.00   0.887
    . 
    .
```

Where the first column is the line number and the second column is the average values for data. I shall explain bit detail for clarity purpose. In the above example, **0.112** is the average for all data in first line from each file. And **0.324** is the average value for all data in second line from each file.

What I want is the code which can accomplish this calculation.

I have tried with perl for openning a file. But lost when trying to figure out to convert the idea into code. The perl that I wrote is as below

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

open (FILE, "file1.dat") or die $!;
while (<FILE>) {
chomp;
print "$_\n";
}
close (FILE);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot almost everything about bash scripting. but I think you can do something like this.

```
files=(file1 file2 file3 file4)
for i in `seq  4`
do
  j=$(($i-1))
  f[$j]=`cat ./temp/${files[$i]} | awk '{print $2}' `
done

for i in `seq 0 1799`
do
  sum=0
  rowValue=0
  for j in `seq 0 3`
  do
    fileContent=(${f[$j]})
    rowValue=`echo ${fileContent[$i]} `
    sum=$(($sum + $rowValue))    
  done
  echo "sum is" $i $sum
done
```

Answer (score 0):

you were asking about the guidance, not the codes, then I could tell my idea with gawk.

gawk has `ARGC` and `ARGIND` and `ARGV` which you could use to identify which file. and for each file each line save data, or only the data you need into a 2-d array. like `array[file,line]`

finally  in END block, you do loop, and average calculation, print the result

if you don't know about awk, you could apply that idea in python too, I guess (not sure) perl should work with that as well.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Open all the input files on separate file handles, and open the output file. Execute a loop reading a line from each input file, adding all the values together and dividing by the number of files, and writing the results to the output file.